# How to add right arrow for sub-child and down arrow for child menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

I have a php form. Here drop down menu is created with php mysql. Menu is simple menu. I need to add `right arrow` for sub-child and `down arrow` for child menu with css. I am unable to modify the css. Plz suggest me how to make this drop down menu more attractive.

```
<style>
ul {list-style: none; padding: 0;  margin: 0; background: #1bc2a2;}
ul li {display: block; position: relative; float: left; background: #1bc2a2;}
li ul { display: none; }
ul li a {display: block; padding: 1em; text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap; color: #fff;}
ul li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }
li:hover > ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
li:hover li { float: none; }
li:hover a { background: #1bc2a2; }
li:hover li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }
.main-navigation li ul li { border-top: 0; }
ul ul ul {left: 100%; top: 0;}
ul:before, ul:after {content: " "; display: table;}
ul:after { clear: both; }
</style>
```

This is database table.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_menu(
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        label VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        parent INT DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_menu VALUES
(1,'ELECTRONICS',0),
(2,'TELEVISIONS',1),
(3,'COMPUTER',1),
(4,'DELL',3),
(5,'LCD',2),
(6,'PLASMA',2),
(7,'FLASH',6),
(8,'BIKE',0),
(9,'MOTORCYCLE',8),
(10,'SCOOTER',8),
(11,'BAJAJ',9),
(12,'MAHINDRA',10);
```

This is php query.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nfs");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

function get_menu_tree($parent) 
{
    global $con;
    $menu = "";
    $sqlquery = " SELECT * FROM tbl_menu where parent='" .$parent . "' ";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
           $menu .="<li><a href='#'>".$row['label']."</a>";

           $menu .= "<ul>".get_menu_tree($row['id'])."</ul>"; //call  recursively

           $menu .= "</li>";

    }

    return $menu;
} 

?>
 <ul class="main-navigation">
          <?php echo get_menu_tree(0); ?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: you must add a variable to your function to know how deep your trees

Comment: @Paulie_D  I am using this code but no result. plz help.  `.main-navigation ul.children:after {content:  "▼";}`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this::

```
ul li {position: relative;}
ul li::after {content: "▼"; position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; font-size: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```css
menu > li ul a {
    padding: 11px 0 11px 30px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
menu a, #menu a:hover, #menu a:focus, #menu a:active {
     text-decoration: none;
}
menu li, #menu a {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
}
menu a {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
}
```